# Android studio key store jks file warning

Tags: android-keystore, jks

Key was created with errors:

> Warning:
>   The JKS keystore uses a proprietary format. It is recommended to migrate to PKCS12 which is an industry standard format using "keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore C:\Users\Ot \ccc.jks -destkeystore C:\Users\Ot\ccc.jks -deststoretype pkcs12".

Comment: For those of you who, like myself, can't read French, here's what Google translate says that message means: `"Warning: The JKS keystore uses a proprietary format. It is recommended to migrate to PKCS12, which is an industry standard format using "keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore C: \ Users \ Ot \ ccc.jks -destkeystore C: \ Users \ Ot \ ccc.jks -deststoretype pkcs12 ".`

Comment: What happens if you try to run keytool as the message suggests?

Comment: Please don't add incomplete questions. They don't actually provide any information to the user, and can be perceived as noise by its future visitors. Once you earn enough reputation, you will gain privileges to upvote answers you like. This way future visitors of the question will see a higher vote count on that answer, and the answerer will also be rewarded with reputation points. See Why is voting important.